# Spot Requests Not Canceled after Deleting CloudFormation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template which creates a spot instance. It has the following basic structure:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  launchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:  
      LaunchTemplateData:
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: <my-role>
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: <my-ami-image>
      NetworkInterfaces:
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
        DeviceIndex: 0
        SubnetId: <my-subnet-id>
        Groups:
        - <my-security-group>
     KeyName: <my-key>

  spotInstance:
    DependsOn:
    - launchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId:
          Ref: launchTemplate
        Version: 1
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
```

When I create the stack, it has no issue creating the spot request, and the spot instance gets created. However, when I delete the stack, it deletes the spot instance without canceling the spot request. As a result, a new spot instance gets created shortly.

I was wondering what might be the reasons that spot requests did not get canceled?

Comment: I'm wondering if you managed to find the root cause and fix for this issue?